# How can I prevent random popups from stopping my code?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

First of all, sorry because English is not my mother tongue.
And I'm a total beginner to Python + Selenium (5 days or so).
And I've found some similar questions but none of them helped me (this is my last resource cause I'm searching for a solution for about two days).
This is also the first time I'm posting here.
I'm automating a task where I need to follow a page with multiple profiles and it works fine. But if someone blocks me, a popup appears saying they can't perform the action or something like that. I wanna know what can I do to avoid these random popups from stopping my code.

I noticed I can stop images from appearing by using the code

```
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
```

So I tried to use:

```
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = { "popups": 2 }
```

And it didn't work too (or it's wrong, I have no idea).

I noticed the code keeps going after it clicks the blocked profile and the only thing that keeps it from going it's the popup. I wish I could prevent them from appearing or something like that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options[*"prefs"*] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = { "popups": 2 }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
driver.get('https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/login')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Usuario']").send_keys("######")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Senha']").send_keys("#########")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary']").send_keys("#########")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary']").click()
LinkDoPerfil = driver.get('https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/perfil/vampyxz/seguindo?pagina=12')
x = 1
while True:
       transactionElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='botaoSeguir'][@data-seguindo='false']")
       for element in transactionElements:
            element.click()
       time.sleep(2)
       driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='fa fa-caret-left']").click()
       x += 1
```

Comment: Could you provide the pop-up screenshot? Or the source html of the popup?

Comment: This is the screenshot: imgur.com/a/lqXaDHD | And for some reason I can't take the html code of the popup.

Comment: Also, if you know the answer to my other question, I'd be glad to hear you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768094/how-can-i-open-multiple-links-quickly-with-python-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:
Try using javascript to accept the alerts after every page load.
`driver.execute_script("window.alert = function () { return true}")`

**Try This**

```
x = 1
while x<12:
       driver.execute_script("window.alert = function () { return true}")
       transactionElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='botaoSeguir'][@data-seguindo='false']")
       for element in transactionElements:
            element.click()
       time.sleep(2)
       driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='fa fa-caret-left']").click()
       x += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried and it doesn't work. The popup is still here.

Comment: Thank you again, but it's still not working grgrgrgrgrg I have no idea what to do

Comment: @thatpoppyfan I've updated the code for accepting alerts using javascript. Try it and let me know.

Comment: IT'S FINALLY WORKING. I didn't even know we could use Javascript with Python, this will improve my code A LOT. Thank you SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Also, if you know the answer to my other question, I'd be glad to hear you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768094/how-can-i-open-multiple-links-quickly-with-python-selenium

Comment: putting code inside a `try` block is sure a way handle exceptions. But in this case, the example of the other answer would give you an error if the page shows any popup in the future. You have passed the problematic pages. But there could be a new profile that would give you the same problem and that solution will face an unhandled exception. That is why that answer didn't work when there were alerts. My answer was for handling the alerts without worrying about handling the exception.  And it was faster.  At least upvote the answer for showing appreciation for the time spent on your problem

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle errors that are 'out of my control' in selenium is by putting the code that could return an error in a try and except block. This way even thought you encounter an error, you can still continue running the code.

```
while True:
       transactionElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='botaoSeguir'][@data-seguindo='false']")
       for element in transactionElements:
            try:
                element.click()
            except:
                """Do something else such as move onto the next element"""
       time.sleep(2)
       driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='fa fa-caret-left']").click()
       x += 1
```

Comment: I tried it doesn't work.

while True:
       transactionElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='botaoSeguir'][@data-seguindo='false']")
       for element in transactionElements:
            try:
                element.click()
            except:
                 alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
                 alert.accept()
       time.sleep(2)
       driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='fa fa-caret-left']").click()
       x += 1

Comment: Do you know how can I disable these popups from appearing?

Comment: The problem is not the error itself, but the popup that is stopping my code/program from running.

Comment: This the source code: pastebin.com/7iqct3AX 
This is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/lqXaDHD

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem> I treated it as if my browsing window would always be in the same place while the program was running then i used pyautogui to move the mouse and click on one of the buttons. for this you just need to get the coordinates of the button

Comment: in your except block why dont you load in the url of the next element in the list? does that not work? It's a bit difficult because I don't know what your program is trying to achieve

Comment: Basically, I have this list of users I need to follow. My code skips the ones I'm already following. Do you have any idea of how I can actually click the "OK" button?

Comment: Because I think my code will keep going if I just close this notification.

Comment: `Import pyautogui`. First determine the x and y co-ordinates of the button you want to click. These can be anywhere withing the are of the button, and then: `pyautogui.click(x,y)`. Where x and y are the co-ordinates of the 'OK' button on your screen and also provided that your window is in front the whole time. If you don't have the library the `$   pip install pyautogui`

Comment: @thatpoppyfan Just incase you're using ```pyautogui.click()``` I think you should put this on the line before. ```driver.maximise_window()``` so that you ensure that the browsing window is in front when you are clicking.